# Access pictures on a Windows Phone 7 from a Windows 8 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8

I am trying to access images on a Nokia Lumia 610 from a Windows 8 C# application. As it has been pointed out in other posts, such an access has only been possible via Zune and Window Phones would not even be directly visible in Windows 8.

However, using the Windows 8 RTM version I now noticed that the Lumia 610 becomes visible as a device. Still StorageDevice.FromId() raises an exception.

So my question: does the previously valid information ("access to folders on Windows Phones is only possible via Zune") still hold? If not, how can I create a StorageFolder object for a Windows Phone in a Metro/C# application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'd be able to use any WP7 device as a StorageDevice. If I recall correctly, Windows Phone 7 uses IsolatedStorage for storing any and all content, and as such you can't access the  files on a Windows Phone through Windows Explorer without rooting/jailbreaking your Windows Phone. And even then, you wouldn't be able to access it through a Windows 8 App AND pass certification at the same time.